# DOMContentLoaded never raised in BHO (IE9)

Tags: c++, internet-explorer-9, bho

I want to listen to the `DOMContentLoaded` event in a BHO for Internet Explorer 9. I've attached the event to the `IHTMLDocument3` in the NavigateComplete2 event without success (attachment goes fine, but the event does not trigger).

I've done something similar for onload: I've attached the event "onload" to the `IHTMLWindow3`. It works fine in this case.

I know that the DOM is not completely loaded when NavigateComplete2 triggers because I cannot access the BODY of the page at that time.

How can I capture `DOMContentLoaded` in a BHO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why `DOMContentLoaded` isn't firing. The most logical explanation is that it's already fired by the time you handle `NavigateComplete2`, though it's a bit strange that you can't access the whole DOM in that case. What's the `readyState` of the document inside the handler?

Anyway, a better solution might be to register a sink for `OnReadyStateChange`, something like this:

```
class CDocumentSink :
  public IDispEventImpl<1, CDocumentSink, &DIID_HTMLDocumentEvents2, &LIBID_MSHTML, 4, 0>
{
public:
  BEGIN_SINK_MAP(CDocumentSink)
    SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_HTMLDocumentEvents2, DISPID_READYSTATECHANGE, OnReadyStateChange)
  END_SINK_MAP()

  STDMETHOD_(void, OnReadyStateChange)(IHTMLEventObj* ev);
};
```

You could implement this as part of an existing or make a separate class (as in the above example). When the `readyState` is 4 (complete) the DOM should be there and usable.